# how to make a button scroll the window a certain height

Tags: javascript

I am trying to have the window do a smooth scroll effect when a button is clicked. 
At the moment I have this as the following code.

```
<div class="scroll-button" href="#thanks"><span></span>Scroll</div>

var scrollButton = document.querySelector('.scroll-button');
scrollButton.addEventListener("click", smoothScrollButton);

function smoothScrollButton() {
  var scrollTheWindowButton = document.querySelector('html, body');
  for (var i = 0; i <  scrollTheWindowButton.length; i++) {
    scrollTheWindowButton[i].animate([{scrollTop = this.offsetTop}], 500, 'linear' 
    )};
  }
```

I'm currently not seeing any errors in VSC and well as the console, so as a nooby its making this a little bit hard to debug. I tried to look at the .animate() function on MDN, but idk if i am making progress.

Please help?

Comment: `.animate()` is a jQuery function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that effect with no JS, simply by inserting an `<a>` tag in your html document at the height of the section you want the screen to scroll on click. You use the href attribute of the `<a>` tag to indicate the id of that section.

**Html file:**

```
<body>
    <div id="section-foo"></div>
    ...
    <a href="#section-foo">Take me foo</a>
</body>
```

You can build a wrapper around the `<a>` tag and apply your styles there in order to get a nice button (`text-decoration: none, background-color: some-color, border-radius: 3px;` etc).

**EDITED:**

In order for the screen to actually scroll smoothly, you need to add the `scroll-behavior: smooth;` attribute to the body tag in your css stylesheet.

I have this on my every work sheet just as a boilerplate.

```
*{
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

Comment: Wow.. why do so many people use javascript for this? is it to give it a nice custom scroll speed and effect? like a smooth scroll?

Comment: Well, you definitely can have more control over the variables of the movement if you use JS, but if your objective is simply to scroll smoothly, plain HTML and CSS pretty much do the trick.